# Is there a generic way to assign a new object's value to an original object's value of the same class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, valueinjecter

I have an Original Document object which has subclasses and properties. I have a different object, which is a subset of this object which holds values entered from a form, a view model if you like. Since both object are from the same class the structure is identical.

Is there a way to generically assign values from the new object to the original object? My current approach is explicit:

```
            myOrigDoc.Introduction.Name = myDoc.Introduction.Name;
            myOrigDoc.Introduction.Clients[0].Firstname =    
            myDoc.Introduction.Clients[0].Firstname;
```

Also I want to ensure that only the properties with values (not null) are assigned.

Can this be done?

Many thanks in advance,

Ed

EDIT: Experimentation with ValueInjector, and its class to prevent nulls being assigned.

```
public class StrNotNull: ConventionInjection
{
    protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
    {
        return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name && c.SourceProp.Value != null;
    }

    //protected override object SetValue(ConventionInfo c)
    //{
    //    return c.SourceProp.Value.ToString();
    //}
}
```

The code that calls this:

```
        myOrigDoc.InjectFrom<StrNotNull>(myDoc);
```

EDIT2: Possible code for Automapper use. Although not sure as yet about ignoring nulls, and thus really doing a merge.

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Document, Document>();
        myOrigDoc = Mapper.Map<Document, Document>(myDoc);
```

Thanks in advance for any advice and help.

Comment: Have you seen AutoMapper - its quite handy for things like this. Even when it isn't subclasses. It also allows for customizations for not mapping null properties by defining your mappings https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes I know about Automapper, not used d yet though. However does this not still require me to create mappings for the above ie Introduction.Name = Introduction.Name? If so I might as well just do the assignments in code explicitly. Apologies if I am missing something.

Comment: Yes you would have to define the mappings. Maybe this one would be easier- you would just have to call InjectFrom - http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you use AutoMapper, beware Lazy Loading proxies, it doesn't handle them.

Comment: Just experimenting with valueinjecter. It does looks promising. However I am have problems with trapping the nulls. I think it is to do with the fact that some of my properties contain objects which are themselves null, but I guess the property itself is not. See edit in question.

Comment: Yes I think I am correct. Looking at the debugged I need to check whether the count=0 for these properties that contain list of object of other classes. However I am unsure how to test for the "Count=0" in the " Match(ConventionInfo c)" method. Any help really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @KD7, since you suggested  VI, then I ought to award your comment as the answer. So if you can place as an answer then I will award. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoMapper, the object-to-object mapper for this task. The library and documentation can be found at http://automapper.org/

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying to get my head around this, since I have only one class (Document) and 2 instantiations of it. I have my Original Object(Object1) and an object(Object2) that is returned from a view which becomes a subset since only a limited set of form fields are used. Also since I am using Model Binding then Object2 is contains nulls for all the missing properties. In Automapper what would the code look like to "Merge" this Object2 into Object1 please. I did try this with ValueInjecter, but could not get it to work. Thanks

Comment: I have added what I think it could be, as an edit in my question above.

Comment: I ended up using ValueInjector as I discovered an issue with Nested Classes and AM. So I will keep AM under review as it looks excellent in so many respects. So I feel I need to award the answer to KD7 for suggesting VI. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com) may solve the problem you need